# Jenkins shutdown when stopping tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins 1.452 as a Windows service and created a job that would listen to a certain repository every 5 minutes and update the local repository and do a compile.

Scenario:

- Update local repo.
- Shutdown tomcat.
- Compile project using ant script.
- start tomcat.
- run flexmonkey test.

Problem:

On number 2 step, when stopping tomcat, Jenkins suddenly dies (service stops) and the job is just stuck. I have tried stopping tomcat using its PID but the problem when starting again the tomcat it will stop the Jenkins service. Has anyone encountered this kind of problem?

I configured Jenkins to use different port to prevent conflict in tomcat ports using.

---

After digging through tomcat batch files I've noticed that `startup.bat` and `shutdown.bat` have been modified. Since I've installed jenkins in our test machine in which anyone can modify its setup, noticed that in `startup.bat` command `taskkill java.exe` have been appended before starting the tomcat as well as in `shutdown.bat` same command appended in the last line which is pretty dumb. The problem was solved by removing those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using Tomcat to host Jenkins. Run Jenkins stand-alone.

Comment: If stand-alone you mean running Jenkins using this command java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=12000 ajp13Port=11000  then yes it's stand-alone.

Comment: Why do you have AJP port set? What happens if you set it to -1?

Comment: Same thing happened(kill the jenkins server running). BTW I'm using tomcat6.0.26 calling apache-tomcat-6.0.26\bin startup.bat in running tomcat. I'm running both tomcat and jenkins on same machine.

Comment: Thanks to malenkiy_scot for the replies. Please see the first post about the issue and how its been solved.